# Trying to load a library

Tags: r

This is my first time using R and I was wondering what to do. I thought I installed these two packages but I got this message after I tried to run the library.

What I see when I try to run the code:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the library is installed properly? Can you find it in the "Packages" tab on the right hand side of the Rstudio interface?

Comment: It's possible that you ran the command to install, but it failed for some reason without notice.

Comment: Try re-running `install.packages("gtable")` and make sure you don't get any errors.